# C++ operator overloading synthetic conversion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This example is from "Thinking in C++", I have one question regarding compiler synthesizing the operator conversion function.

**Question**
When object of class Four is passed (in the function call f()), the overload operation () is called. But I am not able to make out the logic used (compiler synthesizes the operation call) by compiler to achieve this conversion.

At max, I can expect explicit conversion behavior, like
1. obj3 = (Three)obj4;
2. obj3 = Three(obj4);
3. obj3 = static_cast`<Three`> (obj4);

Now for any one of the above conversion - how does the compiler synthesize,
(Three) obj4.operator()?

May be I am missing some major point.

**Example**

```
//: C12:Opconv.cpp
// Op overloading conversion

class Three {
  int i;
public:
  Three(int ii = 0, int = 0) : i(ii) {}
};

class Four {
  int x;
public:
  Four(int xx) : x(xx) {}
  operator Three() const { return Three(x); }
};

void g(Three) {}

int main() {
  Four four(1);
  g(four);
  g(1);  // Calls Three(1,0)
} ///:~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `class Four` does not contain an `operator()`, but it does have an `operator Three()`, which is a conversion operator.

In the line

```
g(four);
```

the compiler needs to convert `four` to an object of `class Three` and synthesises a call to `operator Three()` to perform that conversion.
The synthesised conversion is equivalent to

```
g(four.operator Three());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not `operator()` which you have provided, it is `operator Three`. This operator tells the compiler how to convert an object of `class Four` to an object of `class Three`. In `g(four)` call compiler is using this operator since the function `g` is expecting an argument of type `Three`. Since there is an conversion available compiler is using it. In the second case, since the constructor of `Three` is not declared as `explicit` and it is possible to construct a object of `class Three` using a single integer (using `Three` constructor) compiler is using that constuctor to create an object of the `class Three` so that function `g` can be called.